# Why does AsNoTracking affect DateTime precision?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

Given the following code:

```
var dbRecords = _context.Alerts.AsNoTracking()
                        .Where(a => a.OrganizationId == _authorization.OrganizationId)
                        .ToList();
var dbRecords2 = _context.Alerts
                         .Where(a => a.OrganizationId == _authorization.OrganizationId)
                         .ToList();

foreach (var untrackedRecord in dbRecords) {
    var trackedRecord = dbRecords2.First(a => a.Id == untrackedRecord.Id);

    Assert.AreEqual(untrackedRecord.TimeStamp.Ticks, trackedRecord.TimeStamp.Ticks);
}
```

Where the TimeStamp data is stored in SQL Server 2012 in a column defined as datetime2(0).

The Assert fails, and the debugger demonstrates that the two Ticks values are always different.

```
Expected: 636179928520000000 But was:  636179928523681935
```

The untracked value will always be rounded off to the nearest second (which is expected, based on what SQL is storing). When creating the record, the value I'm saving comes from DateTime.Now.

Testing some more, this doesn't appear to be true (the inconsistent ticks) for every object I'm testing, only for records I've inserted recently. Looking at the code and given the way the column is defined, it's not obvious to my why that would matter.

For now, to get my tests to pass, I'm just comparing the DateTime values down to the second, which is all that's required. However, I'm just wanting to understand why this is happening:  Why can I not reliably compare two DateTime values depending on whether or not the entities are being tracked?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might check what precision DateTime.Now returns. Is it equivalent to `DATETIME` - level precision? Also, note that `DATETIME2` has more bytes and more data stored in it, especially for greater precision. So, when you're comparing two datatypes with different precision, of course you're not going to get the same value for a current time. [More info on the comparison between the two **`DATETIME`** and **`DATETIME2`** datatypes, at a database level, here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/DateTime/134800/).

Comment: Thank you @Radu for the reply, but when I mention "DateTime" in my question, I'm referring to the C# type. Since the data type defined for the SQL column is datetime2(0), it shouldn't matter the precision of DateTime.Now. Completely regardless of data type precision, why are the DateTime values different if the entity is tracked or not tracked by EF6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out, so answering my own question; I found I left off what turns out to be a key piece of information here. I mentioned that this issue came up in testing. What I didn't mention is that we're inserting the records and then testing all within a single transaction, and within a single DbContext.

Because I use the same DbContext for all work, the Alert objects that are inserted for testing are cached. When I query the objects using AsNoTracking, the DbContext has to refresh the objects before giving them back to me (since their current state isn't being tracked, and therefore is unknown to EF), apparently without updating what's in the cache (since we told EF we don't want to track the objects).

Querying for the same objects without AsNoTracking results in a cache hit; those objects that were inserted are still in the cache, so the cached versions are returned.

Given that, it's clear why the Ticks aren't matching up. The non-cached objects are pulling the DateTime values from the database, where the precision is defined to only store the time down the nearest second. The cached objects have the original DateTime.Now values, which stores the time down to ms. This explains why the Ticks don't match between the two DateTimes, even though both objects represent the same underlying database record.